# how to categorise array objects in swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I am planning an app in which the user will be able to select multiple criteria, e.g. hot, cold, fish, vegetarian, etc. The user will be able to select multiple criteria making the search more specific. If the user select the hot and fish criteria, the app will show results for all the hot dishes that include fish. The dishes will all be in an array. How would I be able to "tag" the objects in the array so that only the objects that are within the category selected by the user show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is actually very broad, and there are many approaches to it.

One solution is to give each dish an array of tags. Then you can filter the array for occurrences of certain tags and show the result.

The code for that is really straight forward.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I've never tried this before, and I haven't use tags before, so I was just wondering, how do I add tags to an object?

Comment: I'd make it an array of strings.